# How to copy the latest file from one directory to another

Tags: c#, file-io

Hi guys i am still new in C#, i have files in a directory in c:\SourceFolder which are concatenated with a date string in the format FileName_YYYYMMDD looking like 
this:

```
report_20130220.text,
report_20130222.text,
report_20130228.text,
```

i want to copy only the file with the maximum date e.g(report_20130228.text) to another directory, please see the code but it copies all the files what am i not doing right?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Program copy = new Program();
        DirectoryInfo sourcedinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Input");
        DirectoryInfo destinfo = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Users\Output");

        copy.CopyAll(sourcedinfo, destinfo);
        Console.Read();
    }
    public void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
    {
        try
        {
            //check if the target directory exists
            if (Directory.Exists(target.FullName) == false)
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);
            }

            //copy all the files into the new directory

            foreach (FileInfo fi in source.GetFiles())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(@"Copying {0}\{1}", target.FullName, fi.Name);

                  fi.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.ToString(), fi.Name), true);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("Success");
        }
        catch (IOException ie)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ie.Message);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: you don't filter the file list anywhere....Also your decription of source location does not match the code...The method is called CopyAll() and you are asking why it copies all files? I'm kind of assuming you found this code somewhere?

Comment: that is why i stated clearly that i am new to C#, thanks for your help though, at least i tried something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DateTime myFileDate = source.GetFiles().Max(i => DateTime.ParseExact(i.Name.Substring(7, 8), "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
FileInfo myFile = source.GetFiles().Single(i => i.Name == "report_" + myFileDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".text");
myFile.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.ToString(), myFile.Name), true);
```

Comment: FileInfo myFile = source.GetFiles().Single(i => i.Name ==  "report_" + myFileDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".text");

this gives a null Exception

Answer (score 1):

I have ordered the list on basis of creation time and selected it. there are possibility that you have to check and change it but only minor.

```
public void CopyAll(DirectoryInfo source, DirectoryInfo target)
{
    try
    {
        //check if the target directory exists
        if (Directory.Exists(target.FullName) == false)
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(target.FullName);
        }

        //copy all the files into the new directory
        // Modified from here
            DateTime latestDate = source.GetFiles().Max(x => DateTime.ParseExact(x.Name.Substring(x.Name.IndexOf('_') + 1), "yyyyMMdd", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));

           FileInfo fileInfo = source.GetFiles().Single(x => x.Name == "report_" + latestDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".text");

            Console.WriteLine(@"Copying {0}\{1}", target.FullName, fileInfo.Name);

              fileInfo.CopyTo(Path.Combine(target.ToString(), fileInfo.Name), true);
        //ends here

        Console.WriteLine("Success");
    }
    catch (IOException ie)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ie.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this will create a problem when the creation date of report_20130222.text is greater that the creation date of report_20130228.text where as i want the Max date

Comment: I got your point but in general scenrio I assume it will not happen. neways I will modify the code accrodingly

Comment: thank you so much however this gives  System.Invalid.OperationException 

    FileInfo fileInfo =
    source.GetFiles().Single(x => x.Name ==         "report_" +  
    latestDate.ToString("yyyyMMdd") + ".text");

Comment: check what is coming in latestDate. its the value coming correct?

Answer (score 1):

Select last files (works if file names don't have dots or underscores):

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> lastFiles = 
 source.EnumerateFiles()
       .Select(f => new {
            File = f,
            Name = f.Name.Split('_')[0],
            Date = DateTime.ParseExact(f.Name.Split('_', '.')[1], "yyyyMMdd",
                                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
       })
       .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
       .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).First().File);
```

Then just copy hose files.

---

If it is possible for file names to contain dots or underscores, then use regular expression to extract name and date:

```
IEnumerable<FileInfo> lastFiles = 
 source.EnumerateFiles()
       .Select(f => {
           Match match = Regex.Match(f.Name, @"(?<name>.+)_(?<date>\d{8})\.\w+");
           return new {
              File = f,
              Name = match.Groups["name"].Value,
              Date = DateTime.ParseExact(match.Groups["date"].Value, "yyyyMMdd",
                                         CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) 
           };
        })
       .GroupBy(x => x.Name)
       .Select(g => g.OrderByDescending(x => x.Date).First().File);
```

Comment: this is working like a bomb thank you so much - lazyberezovsky